# Python: No module named core.exceptions

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get Google AppEngine to work on my Debian box and am getting the following error when I try to access my page:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named core.exceptions
```

The same app works fine for me when I run it on my other Ubuntu box, so I know it's not a problem with the app itself. However, I need to get it working on this Debian box. It originally had python 2.4 but after AppEngine complained about it I installed the python2.5 and python2.5-dev packages (to no avail).

I saw on this [Google Group post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/8f2459d2df9d735a/df2b1e9bb76f87c0?show_docid=df2b1e9bb76f87c0&fwc=1) that it may be due to the version of AppEngine and just to reinstall it, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Edit 1: Also tried uninstalling python2.4 and 2.5 then reinstalling 2.5, which also didn't work.

Edit 2: Turns out when I made AppEngine into a CVS project it didn't add the core directory into my project, so when I checked it out there literally was no module named core.exceptions. Re-downloading that folder resolved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`core.exceptions` is part of django; what version of django do you have installed? The AppEngine comes with the appropriate version for whatever release you've downloaded (in the lib/django directory). It can be installed by going to that directory and running **`python setup.py install`**